# jquery pass value into function AFTER function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to javascript & jQuery. I'm trying to create a feature for my site that let's people display badges they have earned on their own site (and I would supply a bit of code they could just copy/paste). I had someone help me with the javascript and I have it working perfectly, but I can't find any jQuery documents that explains it to me?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function(id) {
    // include js via php file with the id in as a parameter
   })("myid");
</script>
```

The id is passed in the area labeled "myid", in jQuery can you pass in a static variable this way? When I try to delete `("myid")` and change it to `var id = 'myid'`, the function no longer works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The occurrence of `"myid"` in the code you are showing is not a static variable. It is a string literal that is being passed as an argument to an anonymous function. The anonymous function is declared and then is immediately getting called.

If you are wondering why the programmer wrote the JavaScript the way they did. The following might help.

Both of the examples below will display "myid" in an alert:

Example 1:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var id = 'myid';
alert(id);
</script>
```

Example 2:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function(id) {
    alert(id);
})('myid');
</script>
```

The first example declares "id" as a variable. It is a global variable and is actually added as a property to the `window` object. The second example defines an anonymous function and immediately calls it, passing in `'myid'` as the value of the "id" parameter. This technique avoids using a global variable.

Of course, you could also avoid the global variable by doing the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
    var id = 'myid';
    alert(id);
})();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you stick `"myid"` in a variable and then pass in that variable, it'll work. Like this:

```
var memberID = "myid";
(function(id) {
    // include js via php file with the id in as a parameter
})(memberID);
```

If you say this...

```
(function(id) {
    // include js via php file with the id in as a parameter
})(var id = 'myid');
```

...you're attempting to stick a variable declaration in a function call, which won't work. That's why declaring the variable above and apart from the function call won't throw any errors.